# block file system on S3

Tags: amazon-s3

i am a little puzzled i hope someone can help me out.

we create some ORC-Files that we would like to query while they are stored on S3.
We noticed that the S3 native Filesystem S3n does not really work out for this manner. I am not really sure what the problem is - but my guess is, that the reader is not able to jump to specific bytes inside the file so that he has to load the whole file before he can query it. 
So we tried storing the files on S3 (uri s3://) which is a block file system just like HDFS backed by s3 and it worked great.

But i am a little worried after reading up on this [source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html) about Amazon EMR which says

> - **Amazon S3 block file system** (URI path: s3bfs://)
>     The Amazon S3 block file system is a legacy file storage system. We strongly discourage the use of this system.
>
>   > **Important**
>   >     We recommend that you do not use this file system because it can trigger a race condition that might cause your cluster to fail. However, it might be required by legacy applications.
> - **EMRFS** (URI path: s3://)
>     EMRFS is an implementation of HDFS used for reading and writing regular files from Amazon EMR directly to Amazon S3.

I am not using EMR  - i create my files by launching an EC2 cluster and then use s3 as a cold storage - but I am kind of puzzled right now and not sure which filesystem I use when I store my files on s3 using the URI scheme s3:// - do i use EMRFS or do i use the deprecated s3bfs filesystem?

Comment: If you can see your file in the bucket explorer in the browser, then you are using EMRFS (or you are just saving files to S3 as a key-value store). If you can see files such as `block_-23874982374892`, then you are using the block file system. Amazon S3 is not a file system, but there can be different file systems implemented on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is an object storage system. It is not recommended to "mount" S3 as a filesystem. Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS) is a block storage system that appears as volumes on Amazon EC2 instances.

When used from Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR), Hadoop has extensions that make it easy to work with Amazon S3. However, if you are not using EMR, there is no need to use EMRFS (which is available only on EMR), nor should you use S3 as a block storage system.

The easiest way to use S3 from EC2 is via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). You can copy files to/from S3 by using the `aws s3 cp` command. There's also a `sync` command to make it easy to syncrhonize data to/from S3.

You can also programmatically connect to Amazon S3 via an SDK, so that your app can directly transfer files to/from S3.

As to which to choose... typically, applications like to work with files on a local filesystem, so copy your files from S3 to a local device. However, if your app can directly communicate with S3, there will be less "moving parts".